# Can you code JavaScript/React-Native in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Is it possible to code an iOS app with React Native in Xcode? I like the xcode UI better than vscode for mobile so I was wondering if there's a possibility, not talking about simulating cause that's all what I was getting when searching this on Google I'm talking about actually coding React Native in Xcode IDE. Thanks

Comment: No, you can't, no plugins for that

Comment: You can open various file types in XCode including javascript/css etc.
But like Dima Rostopira mentioned, there is no plugin infrastructure like in vs code. Tools for developing native apps are already included. But for anything different you are better with vs code or a similar ide with plugin infrastructure.